# Mapping classes with reflection

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.reflection

I have 2 classes User and UserDto both have a Phones property, all the other properties I can map perfectly.

But the problem occurs with the Phones list of the User class, since being null, I cannot identify what type of list it is.

What I need is to be able to and create a list based on its type using reflection.

```
var list = new List<PhoneDto>();
list.Add(new PhoneDto { Code = 1, Number = 11111111 });
list.Add(new PhoneDto { Code = 2, Number = 11111112 });
list.Add(new PhoneDto { Code = 3, Number = 11111113 });
list.Add(new PhoneDto { Code = 4, Number = 11111114 });
list.Add(new PhoneDto { Code = 5, Number = 11111115 });
var userDto=new UserDto
{ 
     Age=18,
     IsData=true,
     CreationDate=DateTime.Now,
     Phones =list
};
var myMapper = new MyMapper();
var user= myMapper.Map<User>(userDto);
```

---

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsData { get; set; }
    public ICollection.Phone. Phones { get; set; }

}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsData { get; set; }
    public List.PhoneDto. Phones { get; set; }
}
```

---

namespace CustomMapping;

```
public class MyMapper
{
    public T Map<T>(object sourceObject)
    {
        if (sourceObject == null) throw new Exception("Source object is null");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        if (instance == null) throw new Exception("Can not create de typeof(T) Instance");
        var sourceType = sourceObject.GetType();
        var targetType = instance.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        PropertyInfo[] targetProperties = targetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
        {
            if (sourceProperty == null) continue;
            var targetProperty = targetProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToLower() == sourceProperty.Name.ToLower() && p.CanWrite);
            if (targetProperty == null) continue;
            var sourceValue = sourceProperty?.GetValue(sourceObject, null);
            if (sourceProperty?.PropertyType == targetProperty.PropertyType)
            {
                instance?.GetType()?.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name)?.SetValue(instance, sourceValue);
                continue;
            }
            var isEnumerable = IsEnumerable(targetProperty);
            if (isEnumerable)
            {
                //---------Here I need to map the lists---------
            }
        }
        return (T)instance;

    }
    private bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        return (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(p => p.Name == "IEnumerable`1") && propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.IndexOf("System.String") < 0);

    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you considered using a tried and tested tool like AutoMapper rather than rolling your own?

Comment: There are plenty of mappers which use reflection/runtime code generation and/or compile time code generation, why do you want to reinvent the wheel (especially one which will be slower and have less features compared to existing ones)? For example [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster), [mapperly](https://github.com/riok/mapperly)

Comment: If I wanted to use those packages, I would use them. What I want is to avoid using third party packages in my code.

I've already managed to free myself from the IMediator package, I'm just missing this piece for object mapping.

Thanks for the help you can give me.